# Ethernet direct connection to nas

Tags: ip, ethernet, nas

I have a NAS at home on my network but I would like to remove it from my network and use it like a sort of super USB drive for backup.

I bought a Ethernet adapter for my computer and connected it but seems like it doesn't work like that...

I manually set up my IP both on my mac ( 193.169.1.1 / 255.255.255.0 ) and the NAS ( 193.169.1.2 / 255.255.255.0 ) And I still get nothing which puzzles me. Of course now I can't access my NAS on the network...

What should I do next?

- the reason I do this is that I do not need the drive connected to internet and I am the only one using it at home. Also my internet is poor and regularly this drive is unfairly suspected to be the reason.

Comment: What kind of cable did you use? For a direct 1:1 connection without a router you'll most l ikely need a crossover ethernet cable.

Comment: It is a crossover RJ45

Comment: Does manually setting the IP also create the right routes on OSX? Which IPs and routes do you use for your other public network? (gussing public since 193.168 is not RFC1918).

Comment: Crossover cables pretty much became obsolete about a decade ago. Does the port light come on?

Comment: The light of the RJ45 does not blink because there is no light ( thank's apple ) it is a thunderbolt to rj45 adapter. On the control panel it works because i can turn it on and off

Also my normal IP on the wifi is 192.168.1.14. I used 193.169 because i would like it to work when i am also connected with  wifi. However as a first step i turn off wifi all the time.

Comment: I did the same thing with iSCSI interface, perhaps thanks to auto-crossover feature I used a normal ethernet cable. Check if your NAS supports iSCSI.

Comment: well i gave up and used a router in between. Works fine but even less ideal...